# Vaadin - My JavaScript library is not loaded although I used the JavaScript annotation

Tags: java, javascript, annotations, vaadin

Good evening,

at first, I'm really sorry for this probably being a beginner mistake. I've worked several months with Vaadin 6 and recently came back to Vaadin 7 (so i'm still trying to figure everything out).

Attached you find a very minimal example of what my problem actually is. I try to use the very popuplar ReCaptcha addon for Vaadin and I'm doing everything according to the instructions (at least I think i do). But on startup I'm getting an exception, which says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/tanesha/recaptcha/ReCaptchaImpl
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    ... 45 more
```

My minimal sourcecode (let me again point to the attached minimal example) is:

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.recaptcha.ReCaptcha;
import com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.recaptcha.shared.ReCaptchaOptions;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("test")
@JavaScript("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js")
public class TestUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(button);

        ReCaptcha captcha = new ReCaptcha(
                "6Lfv5OoSAAAAAPEbWhNB0ERopfQpRxr8_5yncOmg",
                "6Lfv5OoSAAAAAHa4zmExf6w2ja3vm-8ABKgyepq-",
                new ReCaptchaOptions() {
                    {
                        theme = "white";
                    }
                });
        layout.addComponent(captcha);
    }

}
```

I have the feeling that the JavaScript library isn't loaded and I don't understand why this should be the case. If I check the sourcecode of the website I also can't find the library. If this is the case (or if i'm doing something wrong) I would be very happy if someone of you could give me the answer to correct this problem.

Thanks a lot for your answers. If you need additional details I'll gladly provide those (Let me again point to the attached example project :-) Feel free to have a look)

Attachment:

The minimal project (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40355908/Test.rar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addon needs another library to work: `net.tanesha.recaptcha4j:recaptcha4j:0.0.7`

see https://github.com/wbstr/vaadin-recaptcha/blob/master/vaadin-recaptcha/pom.xml